# I am unable to create mocha report in cypress of all the test cases

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, reporting, mochawesome

I want to create a combined report for all the test cases that are in my project, for now when i run the command then it's creating report for the last script only.

Comment: Which test reporter are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @agoff i am using mochawesome framework for the reporting purpose.